# Can I add ASP.NET Core MVC to existing ASP.NET Web Forms Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, webforms

I have our legacy ASP.NET web forms application. I need to create new pages and I want to use the APS.NET Core MVC project for those new pages. Is this possible? How It can be done?

Just to add, I don't need to keep the state b/w pages from both projects.

I tried to create a separate MVC core project (under the same solution) but can't figure out how to do the routing between them.

Edit: I know this is possible by using **MVC .NET Framework**. My question is specific to **MVC Core**.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to enable MVC in a WebForms project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27553305/how-to-enable-mvc-in-a-webforms-project)

Comment: Granted, you might not be able to add MVC _core_, as WebForms is .Net Framework.

Comment: @gunr2171 yes, this is what I'm tyring to confirm and figure it out. Your link is related to MVC Framework and will not help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can not.  While the objects used by the request pipeline seem very similar between the Asp.Net and Asp.Net Core, they are in fact totally different objects which come from totally different namespaces.  The two are *totally* different pipelines that don't interact in any way.  So at the end of the day it's either going to be one pipeline listening for incoming web requests or it's gonna be the other.  You can't have both trying to process the web request for your web application.

By way of contrast, in the Asp.Net when using the Full framework you can have Web Forms and MVC both coexist no problem.  This is because both use the same request pipeline that lives in the `System.Web` namespace.  So while the way they respond to the request might be a bit different, they both use the same `HttpContext` object.  This is not true of Asp.Net Core. It uses a totally different `HttpContext` object located in the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http` namespace.

You may also find my answer for this question informative: [Is it at all possible to migrate ASP.NET ASPX solution to ASP.NET Core 2.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49358534/is-it-at-all-possible-to-migrate-asp-net-aspx-solution-to-asp-net-core-2-0#answer-49366141)